# Netlogo random values for list bounded by values

Tags: list, netlogo

For my graduation project I am investigating the electricity consumption of occupants in officebuildings. Occupants when arriving at office they can leave their work desk doing other activities (e.g. lunch, meetings, restroom). Each occupant has his own time when going to office and when going home. 
What I want is that occupants determine when they leave workdesk randomly distributed between going to office and going home.

```
to go
 if time = 0 [start-day]

 ask occupants [
   let $currenttime hour-of-day
   ifelse (go-to-office-today AND (workDays = "M-F" AND (Day >= 0) AND (Day         
   <= 4) AND ($currenttime * 100 >= workStartHour ) AND ($currenttime * 100 
   <= workEndHour - 100 )))
       [if (not atWork?) [GoWork]   ]
       [if (atWork?)     [GoHome]   ]

 if go-to-office-today and workschedule-next < length workschedule [
   let workschedule-item item workschedule-next workschedule
]]
tick

to start-day
  ask occupants [ set schedule-next 0
                  set go-to-office-today false
]

 let $Occupancy-Percentage (50 + random 0)
 ask n-of( int ($Occupancy-Percentage / 100 * count occupants)) occupants [
     set go-to-office-today true
     set workschedule [ ]
]  
 DetermineWorkSchedule
 setMeetingSchedule
end
```

now i have only one fixed value for the list. But i want several  normally distributed between workstarthour and workendhour (e.g between 10 and 90 ticks)

to go to restroom frequencie will be 4 times then i want the list to be workschedule [ 15 28 51 73 ]

```
to DetermineWorkSchedule
  ask occupants [
    let lunchtime [ ]
    set lunchtime lput precision (random-normal 12 1 ) 0 lunchtime
    set workschedule lput one-of lunchtime workschedule

    let toilettime []
    set toilettime lput precision (random-normal 15 2) 0 toilettime
    set workschedule lput one-of toilettime workschedule
end
```

Comment: What is the problem? Are you asking to make your task or debug your code? It will be better to specify difficulty itself instead of asking to do it instead of you

Comment: I do not know how to make a list that is bounded by two values. For example occupant arrives at tick 10 at a patch and will leave the patch at tick 90. In between 10 and 90 he can move-to other patches normally distributed by the random-normal function.

Comment: The normal distribution is not bounded, so you cannot have exactly what you are asking for.  Additionally, so maybe you want 4 random integer values between 10 and 90, but this does not seem right either.  It is not really the numbers that should be random, but the intervals between them.  Try to say exactly what you want.

Comment: I am also confused as to what you are asking. If you want a bounded normally distributed random number, you can enclose your request for a random number within a loop and only proceed once it generated a number you like

Comment: The transition from the workdesk patch state to other room-patch state
reflects an turtles behaviour of leaving its own workdesk patch. This can happen at any time between its arrival time and leave time. Thus basically what i want is a transition rule that is a stochastic event and the probability for it to happen is determined by its arrival time and leave time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you now say you just want a `n` stochastic values between two endpoints without any distributional constraint, you could do this:

```
to-report transition-times [#n #start #end]
  let _possible n-values (#end - #start + 1) [#start + ?]
  report sort n-of #n _possible
end
```

This will give you values in [#start,#end] -- that is, including #start and #end.  (Adjust to taste.)  Values are constrained to be unique.